# Midpoints on Riemannian manifold with bounded curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with non-negative sectional curvature everywhere bounded above by some $\kappa>0$. For simplicity, assume that the injectivity radius is everywhere infinite on $M$, so the log map at any $x\in M$, denoted by $Log_x$, is defined everywhere on $M$.

Now, let $x_1,x_2$ be fixed points in $M$.

For any $x\in M$, I want to quantify the difference between :

1. taking the midpoint of $Log_x(x_1)$ and $Log_x(x_2)$ in the tangent space $T_xM$ and map it back to $M$, and
2. taking the midpoint $x^*$ of $x_1$ and $x_2$, defined as the minimizer of $d(y,x_1)^2+d(y,x_2)^2$ over $y\in M$, where $d$ is the geodesic distance.

In other words, can we bound
$$\left\|Log_x(x^*)-\frac{1}{2}\left(Log_x(x_1)+Log_x(x_2)\right)\right\|_x^2$$
by a quantity that only depends on $\kappa$ and $d(x,x^*)$ ?

And what about the case where $M$ has non-positive sectional curvature everywhere bounded below by $-\kappa$ (for some $\kappa>0$) ?

Comment: I don't know how to be answer the question, but if you add the hypothesis that $M$ be complete, then all such $M$ are diffeo to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Maybe you can do something with a global coordinate system then?

Comment: @JasonDeVito the diffeomorphism is not an isometry in general, so I cannot control how it changes all the distances.

Comment: @TrivialPursuit The control of the curvature leads a controll on the exponential map -via Jacobi fields-, thus in a global coordinate system given by the exponential map, it leads to a control of the distorsion of the distance.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $x_1,x_2$ one does get a bound for above depending only on $\kappa$ and $d(x,x^*)$. Let me only consider $x$ for which $d(x,x^*)<\frac{1}{4}d(x_1,x_2)$. For other choices of $x$, triangle inequality provides the upper bound $d(x,x^*)$ upto a constant. Now for $d(x,x^*)<\frac{1}{4}d(x_1,x_2)$, first one observes $$\frac{1}{4}d(x_1,x_2)\leq d(x,x_1)\leq \frac{3}{4}d(x_1,x_2),$$ again by triangle inequality and similarly for $d(x,x_2)$. Let $\theta_x$ be the angle between $\log_x(x_1)$ and $\log_x(x_2)$. Then $$\|\frac{1}{2}(\log_x(x_1)+\log_x(x_2))\|=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d(x,x_1)^2+d(x,x_2)^2+2d(x,x_1)\cdot d(x,x_2)\cos\theta_x}$$ and $\|\log_x(x^*)\|=d(x,x^*)$. One can use Toponogov's triangle comparison theorem to bound $\theta_x$ in terms of $\kappa$ and $d(x,x^*)$. Note that as $d(x,x^*)$ goes to zero, $\theta_x$ goes to $\pi$. The curvature lower bound says that the $\theta_x$ can not be too small.

Edit: In the case of strictly positive sectional curvature, note that Topogonov's theorem says that the angle between $\log_x(x_1)$ and $\log_x(x_2)$ can not be less than $\pi-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ as $x\to x^*$ (you need one of the sides to be small, let it be the one joining $x$ and $x^*$). If the angle is greater than $\pi+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$, as $x\to x^*$, then again Arzela-Ascoli gives a contradiction to an infinite injectivity radius.

Comment: Thanks! How do I get a bound on the distance (in the tangent space $T_xM$) between the midpoint of the logs and the log of the midpoint? I'm hoping to get a bound that goes to zero as $x$ goes to $x^*$ (for fixed $x_1,x_2$). And Topogonov's inequality applies when the curvature is bounded from below, but I'm mostly interested in the case when the curvature is not too large, i.e., bounded from above by some positive $\kappa$.

Comment: A similar comparison theorem tells that $\theta_x$ will go to $\pi$ as $x$ goes to $x^*$, given an upper or lower bound on the curvature. You could check the book of Cheeger-Ebin, for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that book. In comparison theorems, one compares a set of points (usually a triangle) with a corresponding set in a space with constant curvature. However, for such a comparison set to exist, its diameter must not exceed that of the space of constant diameter. So, in my example, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are far apart (farther than $\pi/\sqrt \kappa$, where $\kappa$ is a positive upper bound on the curvature), I can not use any comparison theorem, right? However, I want to be able to handle such cases as well.

Comment: I edited the answer.